# Cells of CollectionView Not Displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im using storyboard to create a collectionview which displays incoming Instagram Pics. Can someone take a [look at my project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9J0YAIS_BJPcFhvdzJ3LVV2Znc/edit?usp=sharing) to find out why it is not working?

****Edit The main issue lies in either the storyboard or the class called StreamViewController.m
The project was cut down for the most essential parts so dont worry about digging through a project.*****

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9J0YAIS_BJPcFhvdzJ3LVV2Znc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to be specific and identify where the issue is... I don't think anyone is going to look through your project to find the issue. People are more likely to look through a snippet or a class

Comment: @waf I just added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked through StreamViewController and you never set self as the delegate or datasource for "collectionView".